# When I use Rule, why doesn't this work?

Tags: replacement

```
k.k.k //. {k.k -> k}
```

works perfectly, so the output is just `k`.

But, when I use `Esc`.`Esc` (center dot, CenterDot[k,k]) instead of . (comma),

```
k Esc.Esc k Esc.Esc k //. {k Esc.Esc k -> k}
```

does not work while

```
k Esc.Esc k //. {k Esc.Esc k -> k}
```

works.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `Dot` has the atrribute [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) while `CenterDot` doesn't:

```
{Dot, CenterDot} // Attributes
```

> ```
> {{Flat, OneIdentity, Protected}, {}}
> ```

As the document said,

> In pattern matching, `Flat` allows sequences of elements to be replaced:

```
 SetAttributes[f, Flat]
 f[a, b, c, d, e] /. f[b, c, d] -> x
```

> ```
> f[a, x, e]
> ```

So, to fix your problem, just set `Flat` attribute to `CenterDot`:

```
SetAttributes[CenterDot, Flat]
k·k·k //. k·k -> k
```

> ```
> k
> ```

Comment: It works but how about this situation? (I set CenterDot to be flat) `CenterDot[a, b] //. CenterDot[x_, b] -> x` This code returns not a, but CenterDot[a]. I don't know why this happened.

Comment: @Analysis You need another attribute `OneIdentity` added. See [here](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_L-O_16.html#OneIdentity-Flat) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
k Esc.Esc k Esc.Esc k /. CenterDot[k, ___] -> k
```

gives the desired result

Comment: For a more general rule, you can use `//.{CenterDot[a___,x_,x_,b___]:>CenterDot[a,x,b],CenterDot[x_]:>x}`. For example, try evaluating `k\[CenterDot]k\[CenterDot]k\[CenterDot]g\[CenterDot]g\[CenterDot]k\[CenterDot]h//.{CenterDot[a___,x_,x_,b___]:>CenterDot[a,x,b],CenterDot[x_]:>x}`

Answer (score 2):

It's not answer but comment

Code

```
k Esc.Esc k Esc.Esc k //. {k Esc.Esc k -> k}
```

does not work becouse

```
FullForm[k Esc.Esc k Esc.Esc k]
(*CenterDot[k,k,k]*)
```

and you try replace `CenterDot[k,k]` (that is missing on the left side) by `k`

Finally write it in more programatic style

```
CenterDot[k,k,k] //. CenterDot[k,k] -> k
(*CenterDot[k,k,k]*)
```

And you last working example

```
CenterDot[k,k] //. CenterDot[k,k] -> k
(*k*)
```

Comment: Well, not quite correct because if you check the `FullForm` of `k.k.k` what you'll see is `Dot[k, k, k]`, the true cause lies in the `Attributes`.